# Printing child p elements of html tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to print certain text from a website out into a console.

I'm trying to print the 'p' tag text which is 'AUG' & '27',but only if the 'a' tag contains a child 'img' tag, but for some reason nothing is printing out.

Here's the html code - (I've underlined the text I want in red')
[image]

```
<a data-qa="product-card-link" aria-label="Off-Line 'Black Menta' Release Date" class="card-link d-sm-b" href="/gb/launch/t/off-line-black-menta">
    <div class="launch-time ta-sm-l d-sm-h d-md-b z10 mod-bg-grey pt6-sm pl6-sm">
        <div class="launch-caption ta-sm-c">
            <p class="mod-h2 ncss-brand u-uppercase fs19-sm fs28-md fs34-lg " data-qa="test-startDate">Aug</p>
            <p class="mod-h1 ncss-brand test-day fs30-sm fs40-md" data-qa="test-day">28</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img alt="Off-Line 'Black Menta' Release Date" class="image-component mod-image-component u-full-width" src="https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CJ0693_002_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&amp;align=0,1" srcset="" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;">
</a>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='card-link d-sm-b'):
    if a.find('img'):
        for p in a.find_all('p'):
            print(p.text)
```

Comment: because the <p> tag is not directly under the <a> but under a <div> so the path is <a>/<div>/<p>

You may want to use xpath to find things like that in well formed XHTML

Comment: kindly [edit] your question and include the `HTML` as code instead of image.

Comment: Please include your code itself as opposed to including pictures of your code.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have now done so

Comment: @Ronan I have now done so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `a.card-link:has(> img):has(p)` which will select all `<a>` tags with `class="card-link"` which contain direct child `<img>` and `<p>` tags (the `<p>` tags can be any level deep):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<a data-qa="product-card-link" aria-label="Off-Line 'Black Menta' Release Date" class="card-link d-sm-b" href="/gb/launch/t/off-line-black-menta">
    <div class="launch-time ta-sm-l d-sm-h d-md-b z10 mod-bg-grey pt6-sm pl6-sm">
        <div class="launch-caption ta-sm-c">
            <p class="mod-h2 ncss-brand u-uppercase fs19-sm fs28-md fs34-lg " data-qa="test-startDate">Aug</p>
            <p class="mod-h1 ncss-brand test-day fs30-sm fs40-md" data-qa="test-day">28</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img alt="Off-Line 'Black Menta' Release Date" class="image-component mod-image-component u-full-width" src="https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CJ0693_002_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&amp;align=0,1" srcset="" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;">
</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a.card-link:has(> img):has(p)'):
    all_p = [p.get_text(strip=True) for p in a.select('p')]
    print(all_p)
```

Prints:

```
['Aug', '28']
```

---

EDIT: To get dates and names of products, you can use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/launch?s=upcoming'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.select('div.launch-caption'):
    print(d.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '), 
        d.find_next('h3').get_text(strip=True), 
        d.find_next('h6').get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Aug 27 Air Jordan 3 Denim
Aug 28 Off-Line Black Menta
Aug 28 Off-Line Vast Grey
Aug 29 Air Max 1 Evergreen Aura
Aug 29 Air Jordan 12 University Gold
Sep 1 ISPA Drifter Split Iron Grey
Sep 1 ISPA Drifter Split Spruce
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I've tried to integrate your answer into my code, by instead of using 'txt',I done ```response = request.get( "https://www.nike.com/gb/launch?s=upcoming")   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  ``` But for some reason its not working

Comment: Could you explain how you came with 'div.launch-caption'

Comment: @coderoftheday I did `print(soup)` and then searched for relevant tags. To print only month and date, you can do `print(d.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))` (without `h3` and `h6`). If you want to get them separately, you can do `d.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ').split()`